# Meteor error when installing npm modules

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

So when I install cheerio using npm, I get this error.

```
Error: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you) - line 1, file
```

I tried to do the same with jsdom, and I get parse error.

Right now I have my html and css in a client folder and the server side code in a server folder. I have made no other changes from the default stuff meteor does for you.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get around the problem by using:

```
npm install cheerio -g
```